# Is it possible to run an AccuRev query at an arbitrary time in the past?

Tags: metrics, accurev, timespec

I want to keep project metrics for my over time which I can show as a report. For example, I want to show a line chart of how many issues were WIP, Assigned, or Completed at the end of each week. Can I run the query at an arbitrary date in the past and build the charts on demand? Is there a way for me to do this without having to run a cron job each week and keep track myself?

**edit:** I'm using the accurev XML shell command to collect these stats, not the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe that this is currently possible with the XML command. We achieve this by issuing the query and archiving the results ourselves. Optionally, I suppose that you could write a script to go through the individual issues and parse the corresponding issue history to extrapolate the state of an issue at a given snapshot, but this seems like a bit more effort than is worthwhile. However, if you wish to do that, you could retrieve the issue history via XML as well, e.g. -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<historyIssue issueDB = "myDepot">
<issueNum fid="1">1</issueNum>
</historyIssue>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid I'd have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to look at the AccuRev web interface as it includes [issue] reporting features not found in the standalone GUI.

HTH _ dave